# Commit point in SqlLoader, Used rows not working

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am using `SqlLoader` to load huge file for this I need to change commit point.

I have used rows=1000 but it is not reflecting while executing. I have tried below command to do this :

```
>sqlldr user/pass@db control=myctl.ctl log=mylog.log rows=1000
```

The above command is not changing the commit point for me. Is there any oracle environment file do I need to modify to change the commit point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also the bindsize to consider. Bump that up to ensure that you get the rows values you want. eg

```
C:\temp>sqlldr control=emp.ctl userid=/@db18_pdb1

SQL*Loader: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Oct 7 16:00:54 2019
Version 18.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
Commit point reached - logical record count 250
Commit point reached - logical record count 500
Commit point reached - logical record count 750
Commit point reached - logical record count 1000
....


C:\temp>sqlldr control=emp.ctl userid=/@db18_pdb1 rows=1000 bindsize=8000000

SQL*Loader: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Oct 7 16:01:19 2019
Version 18.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
specified value for readsize(1048576) less than bindsize(8000000)
Commit point reached - logical record count 1000
Commit point reached - logical record count 2000
Commit point reached - logical record count 3000
Commit point reached - logical record count 4000
```